# Messaged users != anonymous users

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, gravatar

A recent change (within the last day or two) has resulted in the entire list of messaged users in the users tab of the diamond mod tools to have the `anonymous-gravatar` gravatar (according to the DOM class). However, all of these users are registered and aren't anonymous, and thus their actual gravatar and profile link should be shown. And, yes, this is fairly important, because I like being able to click through to users' profiles.

[image: image of users messaged all with anonymous gravatars]

Comment: what? where? I'm lost.

Comment: @jco Mod tools (not 10k) => Users tab

Comment: @waiwai933 I can confirm that this is happening on Super User as well. As a workaround, you can click on the link to the actual message, and it should have a link to the user's account.

Comment: They normally are linked. I'm guessing someone has accidentally borked the UserID column in the messages table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, in ripping out some Linq to SQL madness here some properties weren't coming up to the UI properly, this has been corrected.